# Signed URL with AWS ApiGateway

Tags: java, python, api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS signV4 to sign requests for calling AWS API Gateway.
Using Requests with headers are not suited for my use case hence the initiative to work with signed urls and query strings.

I had used [AWS Sample Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-get-query-string) sample that works great for IAM user creation.

the same Access Key and Secret are used in both cases (IAM Creation , API Gateway call) so its definitely not an issue of wrong access key / secret.

#### The main issue i see is that the signature i get is different than the one the API Gateway thinks i should send.

I've added all the documented query string but still get the below error.

What am i missing here?

Here is the request URL:

```
https://*******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/******?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=**********%2F20170424%2Fus-east-1%2Fexecute-api%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170424T124521Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=**********821742cee7661ef3a0ab1e5c
```

While using it with the execute-api service i had received the following error :

```
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET\n/*******\nX-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=*********%2F20170424%2Fus-east-1%2Fexecute-api%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170424T124521Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\nhost:*******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\n\nhost\n*********'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20170424T124521Z\n20170424/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request\n**********'\n"
}
```

I've Checked also the java implementation using the samples from : [AWS Signer Java](http://codegists.com/snippet/java/awssignerjava_sstergou_java)
but the results were the same.

Comment: You're saying the canonical string and string to sign in the error message is absolutely byte-for-byte identical to what your code is generating on these intermediate steps?  If you are certain that is true, that leaves only two meaningful possibilities: a copy/paste error in your secret key, or a quirk in API Gateway.  For any given request, there's exactly 1 valid canonical request; for any given canonical request, there's exactly 1 valid string to sign, and for any given string to sign, there's exactly 1 valid signature.  It's all very deterministic.

Comment: Understood , thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SigV4 signing and this error message isn't anything specific to API Gateway itself. The signing algorithm and the verification at the AWS end is common for all AWS services.

Can you compare the canonical string that is in the error message and the one that you are generating while sending the request? That should help you identify the issue.

Also, go through the [step-by-step explanation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html) to see if you are doing everything right. One of the common issues is case-sensitivity of header names and the sorting order of parameters.

Comment: I agree that the signing is not different between aws services , that is whats odd here - same code with iam creation of user works well , but after changing to the execute-api service i ger the error. As for the caninical all is the same apart from the signiture that is different. So if for one service it works than we have all query params values and order ok so what is different with the other service or host?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. i had managed to solve the problem by changing : canonical_uri = '/'  to canonical_uri = '/prod/olh/securedbrowse' , now all is working well. i also changed my java code and it works well either.